# $f(t)=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{t^x-1}{x^t-1}\right)^{1/x}$. Find $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow1^+}f(t)$

Tags: limits

> $f(t)=\displaystyle\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{t^x-1}{x^t-1}\right)^{1/x}$.
> Find $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow1^+}f(t)$

**Case 1: $t=1^+$**

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{t^x-1}{x^t-1}\right)^{1/x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{\infty-1}{\infty-1}\right)^0$ which is an indeterminate form

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{t^x-1}{x^t-1}\right)^{1/x}=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}e^{\ln\frac{t^x-1}{x^t-1}*\frac{1}{x}}$

$\displaystyle\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}{\ln\frac{t^x-1}{x^t-1}*\frac{1}{x}}=\frac{tx^{t-1}(t^x-1)-\ln(t)t^x(x^t-1)}{-x^2(t^x-1)(x^t-1)}$, After applying L'hopitals.

I don't know how simplify this further, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$\left(\frac{t^x-1}{x^t-1}\right)^{\frac1x}=\frac{\left(t^x-1\right)^{\frac1x}}{\left(x^t-1\right)^{\frac1x}}\to t$$

indeed

- $\left(t^x-1\right)^{\frac1x}=t\left(1-\frac1{t^x}\right)^{\frac1x}\to t\cdot 1=t$
- $\left(x^t-1\right)^{\frac1x}=x^{\frac tx}\left(1-\frac{1}{x^t}\right)^{\frac1x} \to 1\cdot 1=1$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the logarithm: for $t,x>1$,
\begin{align*}
\log\frac{t^x-1}{x^t-1}&=\log(t^x-1)-\log(x^t-1)\\[.4em]
&=x\log t+\log(1-t^{-x})-t\log x-\log(1-x^{-t})\\[.4em]
&=x\log t+o(x)\qquad\text{(as $x\to\infty$)}.
\end{align*}
Thus
$$\frac1x\,\log\frac{t^x-1}{x^t-1}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}\log t,$$
so $$\left(\frac{t^x-1}{x^t-1}\right)^{\!\frac1x}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}t.$$
The rest is easy.